# Remove NSSplitViewController Completely

Tags: objective-c, swift, macos, uisplitviewcontroller, dismiss

This question is for OSX. I am new to **OSX** programming. What I have is a *ContainerViewController* as `NSSplitViewController` as a entry-point and base controller for the app. I have bunch of observers in this class using `NSNotificationCenter`.
Now when I redirect lets say *LoginController* using standard transition code i.e.

```
let viewController = obj.storyboard?.instantiateControllerWithIdentifier(identifier)
obj.view.window?.contentViewController = viewController as? NSViewController
```

all good. No issues there. Now if I redirect from *LoginController* to *ContainerViewController* because of the logic used above I end up creating another **copy/instance** of *ContainerViewController* which creates all sorts of problems.

**So my question is**, is there a way to either dismiss *ContainerViewController* before leaving or rather access it. SO that instead of dismissing I can just access it instead of creating a new instance in the code above?

1. By the way `dismissViewController(self)` doesn't work as it wasn't presented.
2. I can't access as in *LoginController* when I do `NSApp.mainWindow?.contentViewController` it only gives instance of *LoginController* which makes sense as I replaced the window controller using the code above.

Comment: Why don't you just keep instance variables of the view controllers so you only have to instantiate them once and then reuse them whenever you need?

Comment: how do i get the instance of the NSSplitViewController class that i assigned in the IB as custom class which launches on start?